# Como desparecer elemento quando o mouse sair de cima

Tags: jquery, css

Com este script o mouse passa em cima do botão fica ativa uma div com texto do lado.
Mas como fazer desparecer a div ao tirar o mouse sobre esse botão?
Agradeço a ajuda desde já!

```
$('.zoom').hover(function(){
     $('.zoom').removeClass('active');
    $('.content').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var id = $(this).data('id');    
    var content = $('.content').filter(function() { 
      return $(this).data("id") == id 
    });    
    content.addClass('active');

  });
```

Comment: se a pergunta resolveu o seu problema não esqueça de aceitar a resposta

Answer (score -1):

É possível implementar os dois comportamentos no mesmo listener de "hover" assim:

```js
  $(".zoom").hover(
  function() {
    // aqui o código quando iniciar o houver
    $( this ).addClass( "active" );
  }, function() {
    // aqui o código quando terminar o houver
    $( this ).removeClass( "active" );
  }
);
```

```css
.zoom {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: solid 2px #000
}

.active {
   background-color: cyan
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zoom"></div>
```

Referência: [jquery hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigada!